# Can someone explain these lines of code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm fixing bugs for some application, and I need help understanding the following lines of code:

Here, 
View:

```
@Html.RenderControlText("WFD_CONSENT")
```

Controller:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderControlText(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controlType)
        {
            return htmlHelper.Action("ControlText", new { controlType = controlType });
        }
```

The parameter `controlType = "WFD_CONSENT"` here.
I can't get what the function `htmlhelper.Action()` is doing here. 
Logically, this function `RenderControlText()` should be fetching some data from somewhere, but it doesn't look like it. I'm at a dead end here.
This method `RenderControlText()` should fetch some text which I've saved somewhere, and display it.

EDIT: The Action() method has the follwing parameters: action-name and object routevalues?
What's the second part: `new { controlType = controlType }` ? What does this routevalues do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't get what the function htmlhelper.Action() is doing here.

Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) from Phil Haack where he explains child actions in details.

The Html.Action helper basically executes a *child action*. A child action is a standard controller action except that it could be rendered in parallel with the execution of the main request.

`Html.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")` means that the `SomeAction` will be executed on `SomeController` and the result of execution of this action rendered to the output.

In contrast: `Html.Action("SomePartial")` means that the `SomePartial` will directly be rendered to the output without the execution of any child controller and action.

But in both cases all the processing happens in a single client request. It's just that you have the primary controller action that is executed and rendered a view and inside this view you used the Html.Action helper to instantiate a child controller and action (which could return for example a partial view) and the result of the execution of this view is directly inserted into the output.

Comment: Here this overload is used for Html.Action:
Html.Action(string actionname,object RouteValues). What's Routevalues??

Comment: It allows you to pass parameters to the child action. For example if your child action is defined like this: `public ActionResult ControlText(string controlType) { ... }` you can pass the `controlType` parameter like this: `htmlHelper.Action("ControlText", new { controlType = controlType })`.

Comment: This one comment helped a lot!!